# How to add App Session data in IBM MobileFirst Analytics Console?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm building a Cordova App and docs mention that regarding analytics: "In Cordova applications, no setup is required and initialization is built-in."

[documentation](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/analytics/analytics-api/#client-lifecycle-events)

The problem is that after testing the App the Analytics Console doesn't show any App Session, although I can create custom metrics with this snippet:

```
 var event = {viewLoad: 'Hello'};
 WL.Analytics.log(event, 'Hello World');
 WL.Analytics.send();
```

How can I create session data in the Analytics Console?

Comment: Hi Paulo, sessions in 8.0 are when the app goes from the background to the foreground. Has your app done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MobileFirst 8.0 works a little differently than the previous versions of MobileFirst. Like DoraC said we changed app sessions to be recorded when the app goes from background to foreground.

You can read more about the Analytics API and Life cycle events here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/analytics/analytics-api/

Make sure you area calling WL.Analytics.send() sometime after bringing the app back to the foreground.